# Why a simple button tag gives a CSP violation?

Tags: content-security-policy

I know it sounds strange, but it took me 3 hours to check it. A simple HTML

```
<button></button>
```

was returning either in Firefox or Chrome

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src”).
```

with no extra information, no lines, no file, nothing. I replaced by a `<input type="button"/>` with the same CSS and now it works.

Just for the record, my CSP 'script-src' rules were

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa' 'strict-dynamic' https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js https://api.uber.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsSocials/1.5.0/jssocials.min.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced by a

```
<input type="button"/>
```

with the same CSS class and now it works. Really strange and buggy these CSP rules.

Without a `type`, `button` implicitly receives `type=submit`. It does not matter how many submit buttons or inputs there are in the form, any one of them which is explicitly or implicitly typed as submit, when clicked, will submit the form, and thus - I suppose - cause problems with CSP.

Comment: I’m guessing the “strict-dynamic” is causing it. I use button tags all the time and have never encountered this issue.... but I’ve also never used that particular policy

Comment: @Stephen R why strict-dynamic would cause a button to provoke a CSP violation? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Remove it and see what happens...?

Comment: Somewhere, maybe a browser plugin or some included bit of JavaScript, you have something adding a script to button tags. Something like actually adding an onclick attribute.  The question is presenting incomplete info; I know because the basic setup you describe — a plain button tag — does not in itself cause the bug you’re seeing. Restart the browser without add-ins, remove scripts from the page, and the error will go away. It has to!